# Unable to exclude directories with the builtin configuration file options - pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Following the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#adding-default-options), I created a file in the project's root directory called "setup.cfg" with the following contents:

```
[pytest]
norecursedirs = tmp*
```

This works fine; calling --collect-only shows that all folders prefixed with "tmp" are ignored.

However, when I change tmp* to [!tmp] nothing happens ("nothing" as in calling --collect-only shows that *all tests are displayed* regardless of folder location.) perhaps I have the wrong syntax or the wrong idea of what "[!seq]" is supposed to do...?

**So, my question** - how do I specify norecursedirs to ignore everything *except* tmp (as an example).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would need to specify `[!t]*` to only recurse into directories that start with `t`.   In general, it appears to be hard to specify negative patterns with fnmatch-style glob matching. [fnmatch docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) contains more info but i guess you saw that already.